# warning when using React Hook useCallback when setting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a website with a super simple navigation.

It just displays different components based on the boolean value of a state property.

It's working fine, but I have this nagging warning that shows on the functions that handle clicks.

The warning is here:

```
useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument.
```

But I'm not sure why it's telling me that because my navigation is working.

Do I need to add something else to make it work better?

Thanks!

Here is my little component for navigation.

```
// creat state
const [showCreationPage, setCreationPage] = useState(true);
const [showDisplayPage, setDisplayPage] = useState(false);

// here is warning sign: useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument.
const handleCreationPage = useCallback(e => {setDisplayPage(false) || setCreationPage(true) });
const handleDisplayPage = useCallback(e => { setCreationPage(false) || setDisplayPage(true) });


// navigation buttons
<a href="#" onClick={handleCreationPage}>Create Beer</a>
<a href="#" onClick={handleDisplayPage}>Display Beer</a>

<div id="main">
    <div>
        {showCreationPage && <Create />}
    </div>

    <div>
        {showDisplayPage && <Display />}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useCallback` expects an array of dependencies as a second argument.  That tells the memoization to update whenever the value of one of the dependencies is updated.  If you never want the callback function to update, just pass an empty array.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: thanks but why is it my page working with useCallback when the warning says it won't work?  I'm just curious thanks

Comment: The inner function will still work, but `useCallback` isn't doing anything to memoize it, so it's effectively not doing anything there.

Comment: oh I see, so should I just use something like useState instead? thanks

Comment: I would just add `[]` as the dependencies to your `useCallback` calls, since it doesn't look like the inner functions use any values that will need to be updated.  Then React can memoize those functions and do a little more optimization for you.